# Newfypoo weight chart

Tags: dogs, diet, weight, growing

I got my first puppy, a Newfypoo (Newfoundland + Poodle), he is 8.5 weeks old and weights 10 lbs - is this a normal, healthy weight?

I found this [weight chart](https://newfypoobreed.com/weight-chart/) but I would like to hear directly from current Newfypoo owners.

Comment: We have an 8m girl. She has been right in the middle of the chart you referred to each month so far. Currently 67 pounds. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately due to the fact that it's a mixed breed it is difficult to assess if she is at her healthy weight without physically seeing the pet. We have a few clients who have Bernadoodles (Bernese Mountain Dog Crossed with Poodle), they were both bred with miniature poodles and have both came out to be 90-100lbs fully grown.

You should be able to:

1. Feel the ribs without seeing them
2. See a waist
3. See an abdominal tuck

It is always a good idea to check with your veterinarian on the growth of your puppy, they are the best to guide you with any concerns you have. The photo below is a good guideline for healthy and unhealthy weights (click to enlarge).

[image]